# Why doesn't `jLabel1 = jLabel2` change the value displayed?

Tags: java, swing

I have two JLabels created and added one of them to my JFrame but when I assign the other one to the added one the JFrame doesn't update

```
add(jLabel1);
jLabel1 = jLabel2;
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line:

```
add(jLabel1);
```

You're adding to the GUI the *object* that jLabel1 is referring to. You are not adding the jLabel1 *variable* itself to the GUI.

In this line:

```
jLabel1 = jLabel2;
```

You're changing the object that jLabel1 is referring to. This has **absolutely no effect** on the original object that was added to the GUI.

The solution is as per camickr's answer (1+)

Comment: I fixed the problem by 
1.removing jLabel1
2.jLabel1 = jLabel2;
3.adding jLabel1
4.repainting

Comment: @Mohammad There was no reason to re-assign jLabel1 in that case -- remove jLabel1 -> add jLabel2. A manual repaint should not be required in most situations.

Comment: jLabel2 is a local and temprory object , that's why i do that

Comment: @Mohammad: your comment makes no sense. Please provide some context so that it's understandable. Again, why not simply change the text and/or icon of the existing visualized JLabel?

Comment: I have a map and the map consists of blocks and each block has a different type, the user can change type of the blocks and the code that i wrote here in first comment changes the block type, I can't do what is pst said

Answer (score 6):

```
jLabel1 = jLabel2;
```

That DOES NOT add the label to the frame.

A variable contains a reference to an object. After the assignment statement variables jLabel1 and jLabel2 will both contain references to the same object. Since your second label hasn't been added to the frame, both variables just reference an Object in memory.

You can do something like:

```
jLabel1.setText( jLabel2.getText() );
```

Actually there really is no need for the second label to exist. If you want to change the text on the label in the GUI you would just do:

```
jLabel1.setText("some text");
```

Comment: +1 However, I think the explanation should be expanded as to what `x = y` really does (given the context of the question).